# Yii2: How to make radio button non clickable in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS

$(':radio').on('change', function() 
{   $(':radio:checked').closest('label').prevAll('label').children(':radio').prop('disabled', true);
})
.trigger('change');

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

[image]

**FORM Field**

```
<?php  echo $form->field($model, 'status')->radioButtonGroup($model->getStatusList(),['disabledItems'=>[]]); ?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group field-status-status required">
<label class="control-label" for="tum">Status</label>
<input type="hidden" name="Status[status]" value=""><div id="tum" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="APPROVED"> Approved</label>
<label class="btn btn-default active"><input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="DIGITAL" checked> Digital</label>
<label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="CDP"> CDP</label>
<label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="PRINT"> Print</label>
<label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="OTHERPROCESS"> OtherProcess</label>
<label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="PACKING"> Packing</label>
<label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="Status[status]" value="DISPATCH"> Dispatch</label></div>
```

As shown in images Approved is disable button but still its clickable, it should completely grey non-clickable how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML of Approved button that is being rendered?

Comment: updated question please check